# select2-jquery: How to set maximumselectionsize dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've a requirement where I'll decide Max selections to be allowed in select2 ui.How can I do that. I tried by

```
$('#ChnageLnk').on('click',function(){
$('#SelectD').select2({maximumselectionsize :1});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

Sorry - just checked. The option should not be all lowercase - it should be camel case like so:

```
$('#ChnageLnk').on('click',function(){
   $('#SelectD').select2({ maximumSelectionSize: 1 });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v4KvT/3/).

Comment: It's not proper answer ( also, question title isn't relevent ). Because it doesn't "set maximumselectionsize dynamically". It recreates `select2` with one param. If you have set more options-params/have dynamic data/etc. - you lose all. It's not common solution.

Answer (score 10):

Please, note
that since **version 4.0** of `select2` they have changed `maximumSelectionSize` to `maximumSelectionLength`.

You can find more in this question:
[maximumSelectionSize isn't working in Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487957/maximumselectionsize-isnt-working-in-select2)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#ChnageLnk').on('click',function(){
   $('#SelectD').select2({ maximumSelectionSize: 1 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

This should works with the old 3.5 library

```
if($('#SelectD').data('select2') !== 'undefined') {
   $('#SelectD').data('select2').opts.maximumSelectionSize = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('#ChnageLnk').on('click',function () {
    $('SelectD').select2({ //re-init
        maximumSelectionLength: 1
    });
});
```