# maximumSelectionSize isn't working in Select2

Tags: jquery, compatibility, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2-3

I have a multivalue select, and I want to set the restriction on number of selected items using the `select2` library.

[Documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/#maximumSelectionSize) says that I should set `maximumSelectionSize` during the object initialization. Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select_demo").select2({
        maximumSelectionSize: 3
    });
});
```

My html selectbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="select_demo" multiple="multiple" class="form-control select2 select2-container-multi">
        <optgroup label="One">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>three</option>
            <option>four</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Two">
            <option>one2</option>
            <option>two2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Three">
            <option>one3</option>
            <option>two3</option>
            <option>three3</option>
            <option>four3</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4oqL1jr/2/

What is wrong with this chunk of code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the **version 4.0** of `select2` they have replaced `maximumSelectionSize` with `maximumSelectionLength`.

So, just change the **js** code in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select_demo").select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: 3
    });
});
```

You can find the latest documentation following this link: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple-max

Everything works like a charm:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tk4hymn/1/

**UPDATE:** You can also add a `data-maximum-selection-length="3"` attribute as pointed out in the comments. For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/1b8y9uzh/.

Comment: is it possible to add data-maximumSelectionLength="2" ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk I just tried to modify the fiddle above, and seems like it doesn't work, unfortunately. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/wz2qLj9k/

Comment: It should be like this data-maximum-selection-length="2.

Comment: Nope still not working.... 
$("#affected").select2({
            tags: true,
            selectOnBlur: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 1
        }).on("change", function(e) {
            var obj = $($("#affected").select2().find(":selected")[0]);
            if(obj === undefined)
                return;
            console.log(obj.attr("data"));
            $("#tv_id").val(obj.attr("data"));
        });

        $("#affected").select2({
            tags: true,
            selectOnBlur: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 1
        });